# Local copy of webpage does not display properly in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm puzzled by the difference in display of a webpage in IE8 when viewed on a webserver and when saved locally. In my specific case, its the page http://projects.jga.me/toc/

The page displays just fine on the webserver. When I make a local copy to my harddisk (File->Save As->Web Page, Complete) and view it in the same IE8, the css is definitely gone astray. The main symptom is that the left column is no longer fixed in position and scrolls at the same time as the right-column and that the contents of the right column are displayed after the contents of the left column.

The question is not about whatever css problems there may be with IE8 but rather about the differences between viewing a local copy and a copy on a webserver.

Note. The local copy can e viewed just fine on FF  /Chrome

If anyone has any ideas on tis, I'm all ears.

Best regards,

Colm

Comment: you havent used any php and or mysql? these scripts are serverside. and wont work when not installed (which they arent on your local drive)

Comment: It works fine for me in IE.

Comment: When I saved that in IE9 using IE8 mode, it changed the DOCTYPE declaration. So yes, the local copy is a different document which behaves differently. Not sure why it would do that though.